# frame overlapping in tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

i am new in python and using python 2.7 . Now i want to know how to overlap frames in tkinter. can anyone tell me overlapping of frame (as shown in a picture which is of microsoft calculator) using tkinter in python using a example? This is a different question, i do not want to fix a frame on another frame, i just want when i click a button present on existing frame, another frame should appear above the parent frame which should not completely hide the parent frame.

[image]

Comment: It depends on your goal with the overlay. You can easily set one frame on top of another using `grid()`. However you really should try to work this out on your own and when you have gotten stuck then come ask a question as stack overflow is not used to do the work for you but just help you past the road blocks.

Comment: dear, i am new in python and i have never implemented frame overlapping and frame sliding. So if you have knowledge, please help me with a simple example.

Comment: In order for someone to help you here you will need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you cannot produce a simple code that can be ran and provide a specific question to your problem then you need to go watch some tutorials or read up on the documentation some more.

Comment: You should not be asking for someone to do all the work for you. Try to do it yourself. Then come back with the code you have tried and ask a question when you get stuck.

Comment: are you unable to give me a simple example of my question? @SierraMountainTech

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

1 [python tkinter how to layer frames on top of eachother.](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+tkinter+how+to+layer+frames+on+top+of+eachother.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

2 [How do you overlap widgets/frames in python tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199863/how-do-you-overlap-widgets-frames-in-python-tkinter)

3 [Switching between frames in tkinter menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213549/switching-between-frames-in-tkinter-menu)

4 [Switching between frames in tkinter instead of stacking in eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838159/switching-between-frames-in-tkinter-instead-of-stacking-in-eachother)

And so on and so on and so on.

If you just google what you want you would find many examples.

Once you have done some research and have actually written code and you have not managed to figure out what it is you are doing wrong or what you are missing, that is when you ask a question here on stack overflow and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

You would also benefit from reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

We are not being mean or harsh. Stack overflow is not really meant for general basic easy to figure out questions. You can use countless other forums and Q/A like sites for "low quality / broad questions".

When I first started programing I had the same mind set getting on stack overflow. "Why cant someone just answer my question?". The reason is because my questions at the time were either common questions that have already been answered many times or my question showed little to no code showing what I have tried.

You can get good answers here on stack overflow to problems that range from basic to complex but you need to show effort that follows the guidelines you will read on the links I provided:

([How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: thanks for guiding me but links you have provided haven't contain my question's answer.

Comment: The links shows how you would layer frames/widgets with place, how to switch between frames and if you google the specifics like the 1st link there are links showing how to stack one frame on another like pages. The point of the links is to show what you should do first before you ask a question that shows little to no effort on figuring it out yourself. If you read through you will see something called `.tkraise()` and this is useful place a specific frame on top of another. The links provided are the best you can hope for with a question like yours that is very broad. No context no specifics